# Cannot catch std::unexpected

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++

I wanted to know what header is required to catch  std::unexpected  exception. I am currently doing something like this. I would like the breakpoint of std::unexpected catcher to be hit. I am using VS2012

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


void myfunction () throw (int)
{
    throw "ABC";    
}

int main()
{

    try
    {
        myfunction();
    }
    catch(std::exception &f)
    {
       //breakpoint
    }
    catch( std::unexpected &f)
    {
        //breakpoint
    }
}
```

When i try to build this code I get the error

"Error  2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'unexpected'

Am i missing a  header ?

**Update :**

I realize now that std::unexpected is a function. So from what I understand is that if `myfunction` throws anything other than an int then std::unexpected method is called which defaults to terminate. So my question now becomes if I add the exception handler `catch( ...)` to the above code the breakpoint in `catch( ...)` is called. Which exception is that ? Does this catch std::unexpected exceptions ?

Comment: I typed `std::unexpected` into Google and it looks like it's a function http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected

Comment: @Rajeshwar: So you've read correctly that `std::unexpected` is something that you *call*, not something you *throw*, and you still think it's an exception type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::unexpected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected) is *called* (yes, it is a function) when a function throws an exception whose type isn't listed in the [dynamic exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec). What you could do is use [`std::set_unexpected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_unexpected) to register a handler that will be called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void myfunction () throw (int)
{
    throw "Lol";
}

int main ()
{
    std::set_unexpected ([] {std::cerr << "Unexpected stuff!"; throw 0; });

    try
    {
        myfunction();
    }
    catch (int) { std::cerr << "caught int\n"; }
    catch (...) { std::cerr << "caught some other exception type\n"; }
}
```

Note that both dynamic exception specifications and `std::unexpected`/`std::set_unexpected` became deprecated with C++11.

---

**Updated part:**

> So my question now becomes if I add the exception handler `catch(...)`
>   to the above code the breakpoint in `catch(...)` is called.

That depends on where you put that handler. Putting it into `main` wont help - `std::terminate` will still get called. Putting it into `myfunction` would work but make the exception specification pointless.

> Which exception is that ? Does this catch std::unexpected exceptions ?

`catch(...)` doesn't do magic. It simply matches every exception type, just as a variadic function ([with an ellipse in the parameter-clause](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)) can take every argument type*. It isn't different from the other handlers at all when it comes to unexpected exceptions.

* <sub>The slight difference is that `catch(...)` can catch non-POD-types without invoking undefined behavior.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the post. I just updated the question. Could you kindly help with the updated part

Comment: `unexpected_handler`s are not allowed to return, on pain of UB.

Comment: @T.C. Oh, you're right (according to §D.11.1/2). Didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Loopunroller's answer is correct as far as the C++ standard is concerned, but Visual C++'s implementation of dynamic exception specifications is utterly nonconforming - that is, it does not behave in the way specified in the C++ standard at all.

As explained in their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx), dynamic exception specifications behaves like this in Visual C++:

- no specification or `throw (...)`: function can throw anything
- `throw (<nonempty-list-of-types>)`: **function can throw anything**, including things not in the list
- `throw ()`: function can't throw.

Microsoft's compiler generates code for a `throw()` function on the assumption that it doesn't throw. If it ends up throwing, `std::unexpected()` is **not called**, the program will simply behave incorrectly.

This is why your `catch(...)` in `main()` ended up catching the exception thrown from `myfunction` (and why `unexpected()` isn't called). Basically, in Microsoft's world, the `throw (int)` specification you attached to `myfunction` is about as meaningful as whitespace.